# How to delete more than one (specific) elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

```
lst = {a, b, c}
DeleteCases[lst, a]
```

Delete one specific element `a`.

How do I delete elements `a` and `c`?

```
DeleteCases[lst, a || c]
(* does not work *)
```

How to I delete more than one (specific) elements efficiently?

Comment: One `|` too much :) `a|c`.

Comment: @Kuba I would say that MMA is very misleading in this case: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RelationalAndLogicalOperators.html It says "||" is "or".

Comment: Yup, as Kuba and soandos pointed out, pattern-matching uses `|`, whereas Boolean expressions use `||`. You can read more at `guide/Patterns`, which contains a list of most of the pattern-matching syntax that is commonly used. It may seem weird that they use different syntax, but in Mathematica, expressions are considered different objects than patterns. Unlike expressions, which are used all the time, patterns are not commonly encountered by beginning users, and are strange to learn about at first (I'm still getting used to them), but they can sometimes be useful.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus I have mislead by the useless help files many times. Wolfram should really consider using some of the examples here, which are far more useful than its own examples.

Comment: More generally, given a list `A` and `b`, you could get the elements of `A` that aren't in `b` using either `Complement[A, b]` or `DeleteCases[A, Alternatives @@ b]`.

Comment: There is a [large chapter on patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html) in the documentaion. One of its sections deals with [patterns involving alternatives](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsInvolvingAlternatives.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Alternatives`:

```
DeleteCases[lst, a|c]
```

Comment: That's just what I thought. But why `||` does not represent `OR` in this case?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu It does. The problem is that `a||b` is not a pattern object. Its not even a function, and so `DeleteCases` doesn't know what to do with it

Comment: @soandos, `a||c` is a perfectly legitimate pattern. `DeleteCases` treats it just like any other pattern, e.g. `DeleteCases[{a || c, a && c}, a || c]`

Comment: @SimonWoods I think I mean that in the context of a pattern object, the `||` and `&&` are not evaluated